# Record websocket conversation using Blazemeter using the chrome extension

Tags: jmeter, jmx, blazemeter

I am trying to record a jmx test using the blazemeter chrome extension. 
In the advanced options I add

`http://*/*, https://*/*, ws://*/*, wss://*/*`

It gives me

> INCORRECT FILTER PATTERN!

If I just add

`http://*/*, https://*/*`

It works fine for me. How can I record websocket conversation using chrome extension by blazemeter ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the below details about the extension:-

> Record Selenium and HTTP traffic to create a load and functional tests
>   in less than 10 minutes (Apache JMeter Compatible). BlazeMeter Chrome
>   extension enables you to - Record. Browse. Upload. Run.
>
> The Chrome extension records all of the **HTTP/S** requests and actual
>   user interactions that your browser sends, creates a synced JMeter and
>   Selenium scripts, and automatically uploads it to BlazeMeter, where
>   you can execute it with a single click. No need to install JMeter nor
>   Selenium to record or run your performance test, the Chrome extension
>   will create the JMeter and Selenium scripts automatically.
>
> The extension will also allow you to debug and test your recorded
>   Selenium session on your local Chrome browser. By using JMeter
>   locally, you can debug and enhance the JMX file create by the Chrome
>   Extension to insure your script is ready to go.

By this, I am getting that it only support HTTP/s and not WS.
Hope this helps.